# Cannot get parameter value from url in main page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I searched a lot for the issue. But I couldn't find anything related to getting parameter value from get request in `app.blade.php` file.

**URL:** http://localhost:8000/project/dashboard/1

I want to get this parameter value after user is signed in. Following is the code in `AuthController`.

```
if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
{
    return redirect()->route('dashboard', ['id' => 1]);

}
```

Now, i can get this parameter in controller easily.

```
public function getDashboard($id){
   dd($id);
}
```

BUT, I am struggling to get this id in the app.blade.php file. So, how can I get it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('id')
```

See **Illuminate\Routing\Route.php**

```
/**
 * Get a given parameter from the route.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return string|object
 */
public function getParameter($name, $default = null)
{
    return $this->parameter($name, $default);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have alot of experience with laravel but i think this should work.

```
public function getDashboard($id){
     return view('app',$id);

}
```

Comment: you are right but the scenario is changed. i have to get this id in the app.blade.php from the url...

Comment: as i said I do NOT have alot of experience in laravel.
But I think you can: direct your function to a route, that route gets the Id out of the URL and sends you to you app.blade.php view

Answer (score 0):

Although you can get the value of route parameter using this as mentioned by
`Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('id')`

But basically you are going against the principles of MVC architectures. Your views should ideally be agnostic of this type of stuff. You should get the parameter value in controllers, pass it to the view.

**Passing Data To Views**

```
// Using conventional approach
$view = view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');

// Using Magic Methods
$view = view('greeting')->withName('Victoria');
```

In the example above, the variable $name is made accessible to the view and contains Victoria.

If you wish, you may pass an array of data as the second parameter to the view helper:

```
$view = view('greetings', $data);
```

When passing information in this manner, $data should be an array with key/value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using it's corresponding key, like {{ $key }} (assuming $data['key'] exists).

**Laravel Docs**
You can read more for working with [Laravel Views](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)

**The basics of MVC**
As [Defined by Wschools,](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp)

MVC is a framework for building web applications using a MVC (Model View Controller) design:

1. The Model represents the application core (for instance a list of
   database records).
2. The View displays the data (the database records).
3. The Controller handles the input (to the database records).

**Rule of Thumb**

So handling of input should be done through controllers. Although sometimes we tend to overlook the design principles, but in long run they tend to pay off ALOT.